# How to Fix Consistently Inconsistent Dart Testing?

Tags: dart, unit-testing, testing, vscode-extensions

I am starting to develop my first Dart app on an M1 Mac and using VSCode. My first step is to create a library that interops with a library that talks to a USB device (a Software Defined Radio dongle in this case). So as I develop my interop library, I am of course writing unit tests. I have hit a snag in that I have a number of tests that each call a specific function in the USB device library. I get different results depending on how I run the tests. If I run the tests from the command line with

```
dart test
```

or

```
dart test --debug
```

I get the following error in one or more of my tests:

"Assertion failed: (list_empty(&darwin_cached_devices)), function darwin_init, file darwin_usb.c, line 605."

If I run the tests from the VSCode test explorer, the appropriate tests fail, but if I run the tests in debug mode, the tests all pass. This is very consistent behaviour.

Using Google to look up the error message give a very limited number of entries. Two are related to the error being thrown on Apple Silicon Macs in Intel Realsense camera software and in Quicktime. The third entry is the source code for darwin_usb.c. No real answers were provided for the error condition.

While this message is disturbing, that is not what this question is about. Why do the tests complete without error in debug mode using VSCode test explorer, but not in non-debug mode, and not in test or test debug mode at the command line? Is there some way I can arrange my tests, such as placing tests in multiple directories so that the tests will all run correctly? If so, how do I do that?